# how to give different functionality for different users in mdiform in.net using c#

Tags: c#, .net

i want to create  a comman mdiform for admin and user where when admin login he can access all menus in mdiform but when user login he has restiction....
for example:
when admin login into mdiform he can access employeeinfo menustrip,cutomerinfo menustip but when user login into mdiform he cant use it
please give me code...
thanks you

Comment: AFAIK MDI is an oldfashioned kind of user interface. I don't recommend to use it today. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface

Comment: I think I know what you want but what you ask is basically: "please do all my work for me" (If this really works my next question here will be: "I want to write an app to get rich - what is the code for this" :D ) - I won't do. So please start by telling us: what you tried and where exactly your problem is. From the few I can read from your question it seems your problem is that you don't know at all what to do...

Answer (score 0):

for example u have a button that save's something, u hook up a function to the enabled and or visibilty
property of that button.

the "roles.admin" is just an enum just to make it simple
and user.role is just a user with a role property, so when the form loads it will set the bt nSave to enabled or disabled based on user role

```
btnCreate.enabled = CanUseControl();

public static bool CanUseControl()
{
    bool result = false;

    if(user.role == roles.admin)
    {
        result = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: the CanUseControl() function u can add it in an static helper class, and based on current logged in user it will return true or false if the user may save something

Comment: I want to create a comman mdiform for admin and user where when admin login he can access all menus in mdiform but when user login he has restiction.... for example: when admin login into mdiform he can access employeeinfo menustrip,cutomerinfo menustip but when user login into mdiform he cant use it please give me code... thanks you